# How to use if statement to print a message when having a mismatch error instead of showing the compile error message?

Tags: java, type-mismatch

I tried to create an if statement inside my code to print a message if the user entered a wrong type of input rather than showing the "InputMismatchException" message by the compiler.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Pr8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Prompt the user for how many integers are going to be entered

        System.out.print("*Please write how many numbers are going to be entered: ");
        int a = scan.nextInt();
        int[] n = new int[a];

        if(a >= 0)
            for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                System.out.print("*Please enter an enteger: ");
                n[i] = scan.nextInt();
            }//for
        else
            System.out.print("*Sorry your entery was not correct. Please enter digits only. ");

    }//main
}//Pr8
```

Comment: Does your code run? What error do you get? What does the code do when it runs? What do you want it to do? You have to make sure to address all of these questions for us to be able to help you...otherwise, we don't really know what you're even asking.

Comment: So why are you entering a non-numeric symbol when your code expects you to enter a numeric symbol?  The exception you're getting is a runtime exception, not a compile-time exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check for `scan.hasNextInt()`, this will work for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Prompt the user for how many integers are going to be entered

    System.out.print("*Please write how many numbers are going to be entered: ");

    if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        int a = scan.nextInt();
        int[] n = new int[a];

        for (int i = 0 ; i < a ; i++) {
            System.out.print("*Please enter an enteger: ");
            if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                n[i] = scan.nextInt();

            } else {
                System.out.print("*Sorry your entery was not correct. Please enter digits only. ");
                break;
            }
        }// for
    } else {
        System.out.print("*Sorry your entery was not correct. Please enter digits only. ");
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, It worked perfectly. I got it now, I had to use a boolean statement for the Scanner to test, whether the input is integer or not.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an if statement to do this use a try/catch, it does exactly what you want. Here is a [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/basic-try-catch-finally.html) I found on Google for you to take a look at. For you it would look something like this:

```
if (a >= 0)
      for (int i = 0; i < a; i++){
      System.out.print("*Please enter an enteger: ");
      try{
    //Try to get an int as input, continue if proper input is given
    n[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }catch(Exception e){
    //Handle your error here
    }
    }
```

This captures all exceptions but if you only want to capture InputMismatchExceptions then you could do this:

```
if (a >= 0)
      for (int i = 0; i < a; i++){
      System.out.print("*Please enter an enteger: ");
      try{
    //Try to get an int as input, continue if proper input is given
    n[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }catch(InputMismatchException e){
    //Handle your error here
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try{}catch(){}` to prevent from exception. Example:

```
int a = 0;
try{
    a = scan.nextInt();
}catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("Show you message");
}
```

In for loop in your code

```
try{
    n[i] = scan.nextInt();
}catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("Show you message");
}
```